# How to populate django admin form from model property?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have model which among other fields contains `price` property which is calculated dynamically. I want to display this property in model admin page. So I've created custom ModelForm:

```
class ShipmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Shipment
        fields = [
            'title',
            'price',
        ]
```

However I can't get `price` value in that form.

Here's how I change form in admin panel:

```
class ShipmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ShipmentForm
```

Comment: It's worth updating the title of this question to reflect that it's about the Django admin, not about public-facing forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [ModelAdmin.readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) (Django 1.10 docs link).

> A read-only field can not only display data from a model’s field, it can also display the output of a model’s method or a method of the ModelAdmin class itself.

This means that you can do:

```
class ShipmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('price', 'something_else')

    def something_else(self, instance):
        # calculate something else here
```

Where `price` is a model method, and `something_else` is a ModelAdmin method.

Comment: Doesn't need the method either; readonly_fields, like list_display, can use model properties directly.